# Not sure how to finish this integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^3 \delta(x^2-2)dx$

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

Dirac delta is a symmetric function defined as $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\delta(t-A)dt = f(A)$$
Find the value of $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^3 \delta(x^2-2)dx$$

SOLUTION:

Let $t=x^2$ then $dt=2xdx \rightarrow dx = dt/(2x)$ and the integral is $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty tx \delta(t-2)dt/(2x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty t/2 \delta(t-2)dt = f(A).$$ I am not quite sure what to do now in terms of finishing the problem...

Comment: Btw, your method can work, but you have to split up the domain of integration before you can make the substitution $t=x^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much @podiki. That was what I was missing I think. I will try to do that again by breaking up the domain.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the property

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\delta(g(x))~{\rm d}x = \sum_i \frac{f(x_i)}{|g'(x_i)|}
$$

where $x_i$ are the roots of $g$: $g(x_i) = 0$. In your case you have $g(x) = (x - 2^{1/2})(x + 2^{1/2})$, $x_1 = 2^{1/2}$ and $x_2 = -2^{1/2}$, $g'(x) = 2x$ and $f(x) = x^3$.

Putting everything together

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^3\delta(x^2 - 2)~{\rm d}x = \frac{(2^{1/2})^{3}}{|2(2^{1/2})|} + \frac{(-2^{1/2})^{3}}{|2(-2^{1/2})|} = \cdots
\end{eqnarray}

can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you for your help! It looks like the answer would be 0 if I am not mistaken. Can you remind me where that property is from?

Comment: @MathIsHard It essentially comes from substitution as you originally tried to use.

Comment: @MathIsHard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function

Comment: @caverac , I think there is a typo in the first formula. On the RHS you meant $g’(x_i)$, right?

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Yes!! thanks for noticing that, already fixed it

Answer (score 0):

OP's integral $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\! \mathrm{d}x~ x^3 \delta(x^2-2)~=~0$$ is zero because it's an odd integrand on a symmetric interval.